# Documentation on AWS RDS "migrate snapshot"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

I can't seem to find much information about the "migrate snapshot" option in the AWS/RDS documentation.

Is it correct to assume that it creates a new, totally separate database based on that snapshot and leaves the original database intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you spin up an instance from an RDS snapshot, it creates a completely new instance and leaves the original intact.

Answer (score 14):

The *Migrate Snapshot* function spins up a new Aurora DB Cluster from a MySQL DB snapshot.

The <kbd>Migrate Snapshot</kbd> button in AWS Web Console is currently active only for MySQL snapshots. Naming and appearance of the button is unfortunate. It would probably be more intuitive to only show that button for when a MySQL snapshot is selected and name it as <kbd>Restore to Aurora</kbd> or <kbd>Launch Aurora Cluster</kbd>.

You can find more information about that function in the AWS RDS user guide under *Migrating an RDS MySQL Snapshot to Aurora* subsection of the *Aurora on Amazon RDS* section.

Comment: As of August 2017, the Migrate Snapshot button is available for Postgresql snapshots as well, since Aurora now supports it.